# Minecraft: Why did a villager brought to deserted village run away?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Near my base on a Minecraft java edition 1.16.4 realm is a deserted village which I want to repopulate.

I brought a villager from another village there but he instantly runs away. The village where I took the villager from is away around 300 blocks south and 200 blocks west.
There are at least 4 beds and several occupation blocks in the village I want to repopulate.

The villager already had an mason occupation, is that the reason he ran away?
How can I make sure villagers stay in the destination village?

Answer (score 3):

I found out that it was because I let the villager out of the minecart at too great a distance of a door. For the second villager I simply put a door right next to the minecart, before releasing the villager, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to bring him to the new village, and only let him run around right after sunset. Hopefully, he will sleep in one of the beds and stay there.